# How to move to my application when back pressed in Default Maps Activity?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-intent

I am using Default Google Maps in my android application. For that I used below code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=sourcelat,sourcelang&daddr= destlat,destlang"));
                //  startActivity(intent);
                try {
                    startActivity(intent);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    try {
                        Intent unrestrictedIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=sourcelat,sourcelang&daddr= destlat,destlang"));
                        startActivity(unrestrictedIntent);
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException innerEx) {
                        Toast.makeText(ProductDescription.this, "Please install a maps application", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
```

I am able to move to the Default Google Maps, But when I press Back Button My Android app was also getting Quit. How can I move to my application when back Button pressed in Maps Application ?

Please Someone Help me .

Comment: I just tested this code on my device, works as expected, on pressing back I am moving back to my application only.

Comment: which device u r using. I am working with android 6

Comment: I tested on 5.1 & 8.0, works as expected. Make sure you are not calling finish() anywhere after launching Maps intent.

Comment: @PraveenSingh it is working in emulator, but not working in device